# How do I combine ternary operator with null-coalescing operator in one statement?

Tags: c#

Currently I have this code

```
contract.Quantity = contract.Quantity ?? 0;
```

and also this code

```
contract.Quantity = contract.ContractType == "S" ? contract.Quantity * -1 : contract.Quantity;
```

My question is How do I combine ternary operator with null-coalescing operator in one statement?

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't contract them into one statement, clarity is more important than terseness.

I  would do:

```
contract.Quantity ??= 0;
if (contract.ContractType == "S") contract.Quantity * -1;
```